# Exportar array globalmente com o framework Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Eai galera!

Estou trabalhando com o Laravel em um projeto, e me surgiu uma dúvida mesmo sendo (idiota). Eu tenho estruturados todos meus controllers, models e views, mas eu tenho uma view chamada: `base.blade.php` a mesma ideia do `layout.blade.php` que vem quando é instalado o Laravel.

Nela está toda a base do projeto, e nela eu injeto meu conteúdo, ou seja é nela que está o: `@yield('content')`

O que eu tenho pra fazer na minha view é uma div que irá parecer na nav o titulo e a descrição do alerta, e ao clicar ir para o alerta clicado.
E é ai que está o problema, como a div de notificações está no meu `layout.blade.php` não consigo importar um array e realizar o foreach.

Como posso fazer um return em meu controller que seja acessivel pelo `base.blade.php` ? Ou então eu teria que definir em todos os controllers um         `$alerts = Alert::all();` e retornar para cada view que eu criar?

Print da minha nav que recebe os dados do alerta: http://prntscr.com/l08rrm
(Acessado apenas na minha view de alertas).

Erro ao acessar qualquer outra página que utiliza minha view root `base.blade.php`
http://prntscr.com/l08ssz

Comment: Amigo, sem postar o código fica difícil ajudar. Poste o código do seu controller, base.blade.php e a view que estende a base.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido!

Não precisei mexer nem em meu controller, nem model e nem view.
Não tinha realizado o uso de provideres  e foi com ele que solucionei.

Em meu provider `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider`

Eu editei e deixei da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Alert;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

        $alerts = Alert::all();
        View::share('alerts', $alerts);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Utilizei minha chamada ao model Alert, e com o `View::share('alerts', $alerts);`
Exportei globalmente o array de alertas.